# Sqlalchemy full text search with multiple columns and partial search in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, full-text-search

I have searched a lot about this but I have not founded the best solution yet. Suppose We have following Table:

```py
Class User(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
```

with users:

- Andy | Johnson  | blah blah blah
- Andress | Bush | blah blah

The search should be includes `first_name`, `last_name` and `description` columns.

I want to search `ohns` query and in my result, I want to somehow know what is the column that is matched and somehow the result is matched by exact matching or partial matching?

I have tried single `ts_vector` with 3 mentioned columns, but I could not extract more details about search results. Should I somehow combine full text with pg_trgm functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use trigram similarity to exact information about type of match and column involved.

I made a simple SQL example as demonstration:

```
SELECT "first_name", "last_name", "description",
       CASE
           WHEN SIMILARITY("first_name", 'ohns') >= 1.0 THEN 'exact'
           WHEN SIMILARITY("first_name", 'ohns') > 0.0 THEN 'partial'
           ELSE 'no'
       END AS "first_name_match",
       CASE
           WHEN SIMILARITY("last_name", 'ohns') >= 1.0 THEN 'exact'
           WHEN SIMILARITY("last_name", 'ohns') > 0.0 THEN 'partial'
           ELSE 'no'
       END AS "last_name_match",
       CASE
           WHEN SIMILARITY("description", 'ohns') >= 1.0 THEN 'exact'
           WHEN SIMILARITY("description", 'ohns') > 0.0 THEN 'partial'
           ELSE 'no'
       END AS "description_match"
FROM (VALUES
     ('Andy', 'Johnson', 'blah blah blah'),
     ('Andress', 'Bush', 'blah blah'),
     ('Ohns', 'Johnson', 'blah')
) AS I("first_name", "last_name", "description")
WHERE (SIMILARITY("first_name", 'ohns') + SIMILARITY("last_name", 'ohns') + SIMILARITY("description", 'ohns')) > 0.0

 first_name | last_name |  description   | first_name_match | last_name_match | description_match 
------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------------
 Andy       | Johnson   | blah blah blah | no               | partial         | no
 Ohns       | Johnson   | blah           | exact            | partial         | no
```

You can view SQL in action here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/6356

Comment: This isn't relevant to the question which is asking specifically for a SQLAlchemy solution, not a pure SQL solution.

Comment: You are right but I didn't have the opportunity to test it in sqlalchemy but I tried otherwise to help @memlucky . It seems that my solution helped him that accepted it, so I'm ok with that.